# Spring Event Emitter stops sending events to previous clients on a new connection

Tags: java, spring, server-sent-events

I'm new to `Server-Sent-Events`. I have an event emitter which sends updates in every 2 seconds(using `SseEmitter`, hosted on Tomcat)
I see that the messages are not being sent to the previous windows when I open the URL in a new window. Please see the image below.
[image: events in 3 browser windows]
Is it's an expected behavior of Server-Sent-Events? I nee to send updates to all the clients that are connected to my streaming URL.
Do I need any additional configurations or settings on my application or the tomcat server? Please help

Here is the controller

```
@Controller
public class MySSEController {
    private final SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(100000l);
    private int counter = 0;

    @RequestMapping("/ssestream")
    public SseEmitter getRealTimeMessageAction() throws IOException {

        sseEmitter.send("MessageCounter : " + counter);
        return sseEmitter;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2*1000)
    public void scheduledMsgEmitter() throws IOException
    {
        if(null != sseEmitter) {
            sseEmitter.send("MessageCounter : " + ++counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without code and configuration there is not much people can help you with. Only screenshots isn't going to help.

Comment: Yes @M.Deinum is right. Please update your post and provide the source code and configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just updated the post with controller

Comment: You should create a new `SseEmitter` in your controller method and not share a single one. Don't store it in a member variable of the controller just create a new instance in the method and return that.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried by creating the `SseEmitter` within the method. But How do I share the emitter?

Comment: You don't that is the whole point you shouldn't be sharing it.

Comment: I modified the code to send events to all the created `SseEmitter`s, from the scheduled task. Now all my clients are receiving the messages properly. :)

Comment: @M.Deinum Can this work with multiple clients if the single SSEEmitter object is defined as static member of associated class ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
@Controller
public class MySSEController {
    private List<SseEmitter> sseEmitters = new ArrayList<>();

    private int counter = 0;

    @RequestMapping("/ssestream")
    public SseEmitter getRealTimeMessageAction() throws IOException {
        SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(100000l);
        sseEmitter.send("MessageCounter : " + counter);
        sseEmitters.add(sseEmitter);
        return sseEmitter;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2 * 1000)
    public void scheduledMsgEmitter() {
        counter++;
        List<SseEmitter> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SseEmitter sseEmitter : sseEmitters) {
            try {
                sseEmitter.send("MessageCounter : " + counter);
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
                toRemove.add(sseEmitter);
            }
        }

        for (SseEmitter remove : toRemove) {
            sseEmitters.remove(remove);
        }
    }
}
```